# Project Euler #8 C++ Getting incorrect answer

Tags: c++, algorithm

The question is:The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

My current code is:

```
#include <sstream>
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int currDigit = 0;
long currTotal = 1;
int counter = 0;
long highest = 0;
int i;
string x; 
int main() {
    string digits = "73167176531330......";

    for (i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
        x= digits.at(i);
        currDigit = atoi(x.c_str());
        currTotal*= currDigit;
        if (counter == 13) {
            i = i - 12;
            counter = 0;
            currTotal = 1;
            x = digits.at(i);
            currDigit = atoi(x.c_str());
            currTotal *= currDigit;
        }
        counter++;
        if (currTotal > highest) {
            highest = currTotal;
        }
    }
    cout << highest;
}
```

The current answer that I get is:
2091059712

My idea is that once i has reached its 13th increment (0-12), the value inside of `counter` will be set to 13, and then set `i` as its current value - 12, meaning that i will now be set to 1 and the loop will start again. Based on my viewings with breakpoints, it seems to function the way that I want it to however the answer is still not correct.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You could optimize your loop a little by skipping over 13 positions in one gulp if the digit is a 0.

Comment: Temporarily change your code to use a 14 digit string consisting of all '2's (answer: 2^13). Now, use your debugger to set the breakpoint on the 13th iteration of the loop. Now, step through the loop, one statement at a time, and inspect how the value of `currTotal` changes, inside the `if` statement. Your bug should then be trivially obvious, to you. Learning how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. Investing time in learning how to use a debugger, now, means that you won't have to run to stackoverflow.com every time your code doesn't work, in the future.

Comment: At every step, twelve of the thirteen numbers are identical to the previous step, and there's no need to read and multiply them again.

Comment: *My idea is that once i has reached its 13th increment (0-12), the value inside of counter will be set to 13, and then set* -- Rethink your approach.  All you need to do is have a window (a pointer/iterators to the start digit and end digit) of 13 consecutive digits, make sure the window has no 0 digit so as to not waste time (since the result will be 0 anyway).  Then multiply all digits in the window and check the result with the previous largest result.  Then it is just a matter of "sliding" the window to the next group of characters to multiply.  Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Your code gives the correct answer without modification. Most likely, you've plugged the string in incorrectly in your local environment or are overflowing a `long`, which you could make `unsigned`.

```
#include <sstream>
//#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int currDigit = 0;
long currTotal = 1;
int counter = 0;
long highest = 0;
int i;
string x; 
int main() {
    string digits = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

    for (i = 0; i < 999; i++) {
        x= digits.at(i);
        currDigit = atoi(x.c_str());
        currTotal*= currDigit;
        if (counter == 13) {
            i = i - 12;
            counter = 0;
            currTotal = 1;
            x = digits.at(i);
            currDigit = atoi(x.c_str());
            currTotal *= currDigit;
        }
        counter++;
        if (currTotal > highest) {
            highest = currTotal;
        }
    }
    cout << highest;
}
```

Your solution may also be a worthwhile candidate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and the Project Euler thread for the problem should have some interesting optimization ideas (I'll refrain from offering any cleanup tips here).

Comment: For some reason I'm still getting the same output as seen here: http://prntscr.com/km9bvg
I even copied and pasted the code you posted

Comment: @JohnDoe it seems likely an overflow error on the long. You can try unsigned long long for your numbers. Otherwise, what compiler/flags are you using?

Comment: @JohnDoe in a lot of environments `int` and `long` are both 32 bits.  You need currTotal to be 64 bits.